# how to make the condition in jquery with the best way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<body>
    <input class="forminput" type="checkbox" value="test one" checked="checked" name="VD1">
    <br>
    <input class="forminput" type="checkbox" value="test two" checked="checked" name="VD2">
    <br>
    <input class="forminput" type="checkbox" value="test three" checked="checked" name="VD3">
    <br>
    <input class="forminput" type="checkbox" value="test four" checked="checked" name="VD4">
    <br>
    <input class="forminput" type="checkbox" value="test five" checked="checked" name="VD5">
    <br>
    <input id="checkall" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="checkall">
    <input id="copyvalue" class="button" type="button" value="copy test">
  </body>
```

i want to check out if the user don't check one check box then if he click the `copy test`, it will alert a box saying" you at least check one box."

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#copyvalue").click(function(){
        if (!$(.forminput).checked){
            alert('teet');
        }
    });
```

but the code doesn't work.

Comment: that code doesn't work because (1) your `.forminput` isn't quoted and (2) you're missing a trailing `});` to close off the ready function; however, as stated in the answer, this is not the best way to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, and you're missing a closing brace and parenthesis.

You can write

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#copyvalue").click(function(){
        if ($(".forminput:checked").length === 0){
            alert('teet');
        }
    });
});
```

Note that the selector is a string.

The `:checked` selector filters the elements to checked checkboxes.

This code checks whether there are any `:checked` `.forminput` elements.

Comment: That's only part of the problem, the poster didn't finish closing the function...if you fix your answer, I'll upvote you.

Comment: also, its faster to perform class inputs on elements, since it'll use the innate getElementsByTagname() function; thus, `if ($("input.forminput:checked").length ...`

Answer (score 3):

Part of this problem is that you're missing a closing brace and parenthesis, the code should look like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#copyvalue").click(function() {
        // ...
    });
});
```

As @Luis has pointed out, another problem is that you didn't quote the selector for the ".forminput" elements.  If you quote them properly, it will look like this:

```
if (!$(".forminput").checked){
    alert('teet');
}
```

But this still won't work, because as @SLaks and @james have pointed out, ".checked" is not a property that you can call on [the jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery).

I will give credit to @SLaks for coming up with the middle part of the code that checks for checked elements, i.e.

```
if ($(".forminput:checked").length == 0){
    alert('teet');
}
```

The reason why you use the [length property](http://api.jquery.com/length) of the jQuery object is because every jQuery object is a collection of the elements matched by the selector (see http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery):

> A jQuery object contains a collection
>   of Document Object Model (DOM)
>   elements that have been created from
>   an HTML string or selected from a
>   document.

So if the selector for checked input boxes returns a length 0 jQuery object, it means none of the input boxes were checked.

The reason why you wouldn't want to use the jQuery [attr method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#copyvalue").click(function(){
        if (!$('.forminput').attr("checked")){
            alert('teet');
        }
    });
});
```

Is because the `attr` method get's the value of the attribute for **the first element** in the set of matched elements.  So if every input box **except** for the first one were checked, the code would trigger a false alert.

Answer (score 1):

the selectors need to be quoted,and checked is a selector rather than a method.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#copyvalue").click(function(){
        if ($(".forminput:checked").length==0){
            alert('teet');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: "Checked" is not just a selector for jQuery, it's also an html attribute, see the mozilla docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/element/input.  Also, here's a jsfiddle showing that ".checked" works, http://jsfiddle.net/Mndmu/2/. If you fix your answer to the question, I'll upvote you.

Comment: okay, I double-checked, my apologies, you're right about "checked" not being a method or a property you can call from the jQuery object.  However, "checked" is still an attribute that you can access with the jQuery `attr` method, like so: `$('.forminput').attr("checked") == true`.